# When alternative log in three type user add, update,delete button show and hide, how possible in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want an alternative log in three type's user add, update, delete button show and hide, how is this possible in angularjs?
I'm trying to make the  system as simple as possible.

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-show = "isOperator" class="panel-body">
  <input  ng-model="isoperator">
</div>
<div ng-show = "isAdmin" class="panel-body">
  <input  ng-model="isAdmin">
</div>
<div ng-show = "isSuper" class="panel-body">
  <input  ng-model="isSuper">
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
.controller("configCtrl" , ["$scope","$rootScope","$location","$http",

        function($scope,$rootScope,$location, $http){

               var operator = $scope.isOperator;


                $scope.addConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.addVpnConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.canConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.saveConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.canVpnBtn=true;
                $scope.savVpnBtn=true;
                $scope.addUniBtn=true;
                $scope.delUniBtn=true;
                $scope.savUniBtn=true;
                $scope.addNniBtn=true;
                $scope.delNniBtn=true;
                $scope.savNniBtn=true;
                $scope.addRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.delRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.saveRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.addLebRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.delLebRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.saveLebRoutebtn=true;

            if(operator = $scope.isOperator){
                $scope.isOperator=true;
                $scope.addConfigBtn=false;
                $scope.addVpnConfigBtn=false;
                $scope.canConfigBtn=false;
                $scope.saveConfigBtn=false;
                $scope.canVpnBtn=false;
                $scope.savVpnBtn=false;
                $scope.addUniBtn=false;
                $scope.delUniBtn=false;
                $scope.savUniBtn=false;
                $scope.addNniBtn=false;
                $scope.delNniBtn=false;
                $scope.savNniBtn=false;
                $scope.addRouteBtn=false;
                $scope.delRouteBtn=false;
                $scope.saveRouteBtn=false;
                $scope.addLebRouteBtn=false;
                $scope.delLebRouteBtn=false;
                $scope.saveLebRoutebtn=false;

            }else{
                $scope.isAdmin=false;
                $scope.isSuper=false;
            }
            if($scope.isAdmin){
                $scope.isAdmin=true;
                $scope.addConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.addVpnConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.canConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.saveConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.canVpnBtn=true;
                $scope.savVpnBtn=true;
                $scope.addUniBtn=true;
                $scope.delUniBtn=false;
                $scope.savUniBtn=true;
                $scope.addNniBtn=true;
                $scope.delNniBtn=false;
                $scope.savNniBtn=true;
                $scope.addRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.delRouteBtn=false;
                $scope.saveRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.addLebRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.addLebRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.delLebRouteBtn=false;
                $scope.saveLebRoutebtn=true;  
            }
            else{
                $scope.isOperator=false;
                $scope.isSuper=false;
            }
            if($scope.isSuper){
                $scope.isSuper=true;
                $scope.addConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.addVpnConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.canConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.saveConfigBtn=true;
                $scope.canVpnBtn=true;
                $scope.savVpnBtn=true;
                $scope.addUniBtn=true;
                $scope.delUniBtn=true;
                $scope.savUniBtn=true;
                $scope.addNniBtn=true;
                $scope.delNniBtn=true;
                $scope.savNniBtn=true;
                $scope.addRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.delRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.saveRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.addLebRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.addLebRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.delLebRouteBtn=true;
                $scope.saveLebRoutebtn=true;  
            }
            else{
                $scope.isOperator=false;
                $scope.isAdmin=false;
            }
```

Comment: Show us some code. What have you written so far in HTML?

Comment: Can you please try and explain your problem more? Are you trying to create 3 type of logs? It's hard to sense from your question what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I create three types user , when log in alternatively add, update,delete button hide and show alternatively,but don't show in UI perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In order to show or hide any HTML tag in angular, you can use directives `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.

e.g.

```
<input type="button" value="Save" ng-show="saveLebRoutebtn" />
```

Here, I used one of the variable defined in your `$scope`. On the basis of what you have in your `$scope.saveLebRoutebtn`, this control will shown on the HTML page. If the variable is not defined on the current `$scope`, it considers it to be `false` and hides the button.

To know more abot `ng-show` and `ng-hide`, follow this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide)